# How do I center new google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this function that adds the new marker to the google maps.

But center does not work. Any advise?

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, name){
    new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: name,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 6
    });
}
```

But `center` does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new marker object via the Google Maps API, you can call the map object's `setCenter` function,  passing in the marker's position:

```
map.setCenter(marker.position);
```

That should center the map on the marker.

If you want to animate the process, use `panTo` instead:

```
map.panTo(marker.position);
```

It should also be noted that the `center` and `zoom` properties you're attempting to set in the constructor for the Marker object do not exist. Those are properties of the map object itself and need to be set there.

I imagine something like this:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, name)
{ 
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, 
                                             icon: image, 
                                             position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
                                             title: name });
    map.setCenter(newMarker.position);
    map.setZoom(6);
}
```

I'd also consider adding `map` and `image` to the parameter list of `addMarker` instead of using "global" scoped objects, or I'd forego using a function at all. That is kind of nit-picky and depends on the need of your code.

[More Info Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: Great explanation, but there is one more problem- when it centers, map goes grey and no map is shown. When I add 10 markers with 5 sec interwal, I am just staring at the grey box.

Comment: Depends on where you are in the world. 6 is pretty close to the ground and there might not be imagery there. Use something a little higher up, like 10 or 15 for testing purposes. There is something you can do to avoid that. [Look Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom)

Comment: Whoops. 6 is far, not close. It's still probably related to missing data or the map taking a while to load. There are also a number of other things that can affect map rendering that are outside of the scope of this question.